# What is the purpose of the document ready function argument?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(c) {
  $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(c){
    });
  });
});
```

In this code what is the meaning of `function(c)`?

Comment: @simonzack Sir thanks for your attention, please let me know... what it does?

Comment: It executes when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [**jQuery.on() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler );
```

- **handler**
  `Type: Function( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter ] [, ... ] )` is:

  A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value false is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return false.

Therefore, `function(c)` is the head of the function that will executed when the event occurs; `c` is the event object passed to the event body. Many programmers use `event` or `e` so it would be easier to remember what the argument stands for:

```
function(c) //head of handler
{ //body of handler start
    //the code that will be executed
} //body of handler end
```

On it's own `function(c)` means nothing and serves no purpose; it part of the **anonymous function**, **event handler**, if you please, that will be executed each time the `event` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready` takes a listener function in argument to be executed when the document (the DOM) will be ready.

The `jQuery` function is being passed as argument to the ready listener function.

This is useful when `$.noConflict()` was called since in that case the `$` variable is restored and doesn't reference `jQuery` anymore.

It's usually a good practice not to rely on `$`, since you never know wheter `$.noConflict()` will be called or not.

Here's what would make more sense:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //can use $ safely to reference jQuery in here
});

(function ($) {
    //can use $ safely to reference jQuery in here
    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now, for the other forms, such as `$('.alert-close').on('click', function(c) {` then `c` doesn't point to `jQuery`. Instead, it references the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which *can* be used to get details about the event or to cancel it/stop it's propagation.

Note that it you aren't using the event object, then you could just do `$('.alert-close').on('click', function() {`.

Finally, by convention people will use the `e` variable for the event object rather than `c`.

Here's how this could could be re-written to make a bit more sense:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.alert-close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `c` in your case can be named whatever (I prefer call it `event`).
- Its an `Callback` thats given after a `trigger`
- The `Callback` containes `Event Object` (jQuery [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/))
- The `Event Object` is based on the standard output given by the W3 ([ECMAScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html))

The `Event Object` contains data connected to the trigger. In the `on` function it contains data such as:

- The typeArg parameter is a String.
- The canBubbleArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The cancelableArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The viewArg parameter is an object that implements the AbstractView interface.
- The detailArg parameter is a Number.
- The screenXArg parameter is a Number.
- The screenYArg parameter is a Number.
- The clientXArg parameter is a Number.
- The clientYArg parameter is a Number.
- The ctrlKeyArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The altKeyArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The shiftKeyArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The metaKeyArg parameter is a Boolean.
- The buttonArg parameter is a Number.
- The relatedTargetArg parameter is an object that implements the EventTarget interface.

See ([documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html))

Its not required to use the `Callback`. But in some cases is very usefull ( for example in an `ajax` call)

Answer (score 0):

C is the event listener object.  If the event listener object has any properties then you can call them inside of your function call.  All events are different so you will have to look at the API to see if there is any you may need for your code.  As it stands now the c is not necessary because you are not using it.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/qwawg9u4/6/

Here is the javascript code for the fiddle:

```
      $(document).ready(function(c) {
      $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){


$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(c){

    /*
      c is the event listener object
      some peopele use e or event instead but it doesn't matter

      you can prevent default actions of elements
      like links or form submission buttons by using the event
      listener object.

      for example:
      would stop the default action of an element
      the div used doesn't have one so it will
      create an error and return undefinded
      c.preventDefault();

      another example:
      This would stop the event from going up the document object
      model to other elements
      It's not necessary here though because you are using the
      parent() function to select the parent div only
      so this will also return an error of undefined
      c.stopPropagation();
     */

      /*
      this will display the event listener object it will be  
      undefined on the jquery function you are using
      */
       //alert(c);

    /* 
       A good use for the event listener would be to capture
       capture keycodes of the keyboard presses display them or
       do perform an action if a user presses a certain key like
       up arrow for example
    */

      //you could do something like this
    $(window).on("keypress",function(event){

        //display the keycode pressed
        //which is the property of the event object in this
        //case
        alert(event.which);

    });

       });
       });
     });
```

Here is the Example HTML:

```
           <div class="parent">

                    I am the parent content

               <div class="alert-close">

                    hello im the alert close div container, click on me

               </div>
         </div>
```